# "Folding" links in the blogroll

Tags: sidebar, links, widgets, blogroll

I've got a site ([this one](http://www.dancebloggers.com/)) with too many links in the blogroll.  I want to keep them there, but to maybe have them "fold" in the menu (after some of them showing without the unfolding of the menu)

Any solutions for that?

Update: When I wrote "folding" I meant that, for (a rough) example, there would be a shuffling of the links showing and that at some point there would be a "press here for more links" button - that will poll down more of the links.

Comment: *@Tal Galili* Your description of *"folding"* is a little vague...

Comment: Fold how? There are numerous styles of JavaScript thingies that can compact content. Please provide an example of effect you like. btw that many links on every page is not really good idea for performance and SEO.

Comment: *@Rarst* - As a side note, can you give references as to why that many links are not good for SEO? My experience is the opposite. Further, can you give references to why it's not good for performance? In the grand scheme of a page load in WordPress, a long list of links is not that big a deal. Or do you have benchmarks that can change my opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a plugin called "better blogroll" 
I guess it would help you do what you want .
I had it installed on one of my sites, but site currently down , so can't really test - but as far as i remember it does the work u asking for

http://www.dyers.org/blog/better-blogroll-widget-for-wordpress/

give it a look anyway and when my site is back up , i will re-confirm this

Comment: Thanks mireille, it's almost what I wanted - but would like something at the bottom of the 10 links per page, that will send readers to a list of all the links (for example)